# Mongoose. How to update array element which contains in another array?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have so complicated schema which had an inner array each array element contains one more level array. But how to update data inside arrays of the second level.

I need to update `services` array but how to get access? I have _id of Item, thread number, shift number (Can be only 3 and this not array due to three level arrays it's so hard), and service name.

I need something like (pseudocode)

`getByItemId(id)
    .getByThreadNumber(tNumber)
    .getByShift(numberShift)
    .getByServiceName(name)
    .updateLogInCounter(newValCounter)`

```
const itemSchema = new Schema({
    threads: [
        {
            number: {
                type: Number,
                requred: true
            },
            {
                firstShift: {
                    "someData": ... ,
                    "services": [
                        "name": {type: String}
                        "lastUpdate": {type: Date},
                        "logInCounter": {type: Number}
                    ]
                },
                secondShift: {
                    "someData": ... ,
                    "services": [
                        "name": {type: String},
                        "lastUpdate": {type: Date},
                        "logInCounter": {type: Number}
                    ]
                },
                thirdShift: {
                    "someData": ... ,
                    "services": [
                        "name": {type: String},
                        "lastUpdate": {type: Date},
                        "logInCounter": {type: Number}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Maybe this data structure incorrect and this impossible? Maybe I need to create many collections? Maybe some plugin helps me. Or it's normal, if yes how to get my target data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code in 3.6

Use computed property names to dynamically pass the shift number. [`$[identifier]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) positional operator to match thread number and service name followed by increment logInCounter inside service for thread.

```
var query = {'_id': id};
var inc = {'$inc':{'threads.$[t].' + [numberShift] + '.services.$[s].logInCounter':newValCounter}};
var arrayFilters = {arrayFilters: [{'t.number': tNumber, 's.name':name}]};
Item.findOneAndUpdate(query, inc, arrayFilters);
```