# Change value of a nested objects property in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using `nodejs` npm [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)

mongodb version: `mongodb@3.1.9`
nodejs version: `v10.11.0`

Here is the document layout:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c1bc140a3902a10542df7a6"
    },
    "email": "radoslav.k.marrinov@gmail.com",
    "username": "rikotech",
    "deviceId": "FA661234A511",
    "password": "12345",
    "devices": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5c1bb980fb6fc00eee83b4d9"
            },
            "id": "FA661234A511",
            "class": "11",
            "name": "someName",
            "displayName": "disName",
            "endpoints": [
                {
                    "class": "binarySwitch",
                    "name": "bs1",
                    "displayName": "sw1DisplName"
                },
                {
                    "class": "binarySwitch",
                    "name": "bs2",
                    "displayName": "sw2DisplName"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to change the value of `devices[0].endpoints[0].displayName: "newName"`

I am able to locate the document having the `device.id` and `endpoint.displayName`

This query finds the document: 
`{
    devices: { $elemMatch: { id: "FA661234A511" } }
  }`

I know I should be using `update` method but I can not figure out the how to select the field to update?

I have to find the first occurrence  of `device` with `"id": "FA661234A511"` and then the first occurrence  of `endpoint` with `"displayName": "sw1DisplName"`

`id` is unique in the scope of `devices` and `displayName` is unique in the scope of `endpoints`

I tried whit this:

```
update({
    devices: {
      $elemMatch: {
        id: "FA661234A511",
        endpoints: { $elemMatch: { displayName: "sw1DisplName" } }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "devices.$.endpoints.$.displayName": "diplayRiko"
  })
```

Doesn't work :(.

I get exception:

> MongoError: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'devices.$.endpoints.$.displayName'

Comment: what is your mongo server version ?

Comment: @Veeram Changed the post. See at the beginning

Comment: Not mongodb driver version. I'm asking mongo server version. You can run db.version() on mongo shell to see the version. In any case any server version below 3.6 nested arrays update is not supported. You can see the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912697/mongoose-how-to-update-array-element-which-contains-in-another-array/51913067#51913067)

Comment: VERSION: 3.6.8 (MMAPv1) I am using free version in mlab.com

Comment: Tried thisone: `collection.updateOne({
      "devices.id": "FA661234A511"
    },
    {
      $set: {
        "devices.$[devEl].endpoints.$[epEl].displayName": "EEADSASDASD"
      }
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [
        { devEl: { id: "FA661234A511" } },
        { epEl: { displayName: "sw1DisplName" } }
      ]
    })` Didnt work

Comment: Try  `collection.updateOne({ "devices.id": "FA661234A511" }, { $set: { "devices.$[devEl].endpoints.$[epEl].displayName": "EEADSASDASD" } }, { arrayFilters: [ { "devEl.id": "FA661234A511" } , { "epEl.displayName": "sw1DisplName"  } ] })`

Comment: At first glance it works. Why isn't mine not working? As far as I see the only difference is in the syntax:  ` {epEl: { displayName: "sw1DisplName" }}` vs `{ "epEl.displayName": "sw1DisplName" }`. I looked in the docs

Comment: yes you have to use dotation to refer an array element / embedded docuement.

Comment: @Veeram Ok thanks you can scratch some answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the $set operator?

> The $set operator replaces the value of a field with the specified value.

```
{ $set: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }
```

I suppose this will work:

```
db.yourcollection.update({ devices[0].id: "FA661234A511" }, { $set: "endpoints.0.displayName": "newName" })
```

Mongodb docs:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Comment: I could id my query selector matches the exact nested array element. Now it selects only on level `devices`

Comment: What you have changed in the query?

Comment: Why would you use the '$' in "devices.$.endpoints.$.displayName"? Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: You say I can use `"endpoints.0.displayName"`, but what if the endpoint with `"displayName": "sw1DisplName"` is the second element of the array?

Comment: I mean I could not know the exact index/position of the array element that matches the criteria 1)  device with `id: "FA661234A511"` 2) endpoints with `displayName: "sw1DisplName" `